# cant change the bg color in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from turtle import bgcolor

root = Tk()
root.title("Creacking Email")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("450x450")

Emailtxt = Label(root,
                 text="Enter The Email : ",
                 bg="white",
                 fg="green",
                 font=("", 24))

Emailentry = Entry(root, bg="white", fg="green", font=("", 24))

worldlisttext = Label(root,
                      text="Enter The path wordlist : ",
                      bg="white",
                      fg="green",
                      font=("", 24))

worldlistentry = Entry(root, bg="white", fg="green", font=("", 24))

start = Button(root,
               text=" start creacking ",
               bg="white",
               fg="green",
               padx=10,
               pady=10)

Emailtxt.place(x=0, y=0)
Emailentry.place(x=0, y=40)
worldlisttext.place(x=0, y=75)
worldlistentry.place(x=0, y=110)

start.mainloop()
root.configure(bg="green")  #does nothong and ['bg'] = 'green'

root.mainloop()

#everything everything
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: `start.mainloop()` will block your code and you probably should look up how to define a function in python and how you specify the `command` option of `tk.Button`

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting. In the future, please include more information in addition to your code. You may want to read about [ask]. Also, you don't need both `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *` - typically, you'll use `import tkinter as tk` and then prefix tkinter objects with `tk.`, e.g.: `tk.Tk`, `tk.Label`, etc.

Comment: Missing. Add in line 35  start.place(x=0, y=160)  rremove button parameter  padx=10,
 pady=10. Which bg color?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `root.configure(bg="green")` in the first `root.mainloop()`, the background of your window will immediatly turn green. You can also remove the `import tkinter` and the `from turtle import bgcolor` statements. If you want the background of your root to turn green at a certain time, I suggest you check out, maybe threading and create a function and run the function, once a certain time is over. Or you write a function, that changes your background color on the click of a button or something similar.
Also you can remove the second `root.mainloop()`, it doesn't do anything, since its a loop...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything `bg` changed. Which widgets can change `bg`?

I rearrange .place coordinate.

Remove `Button` parameter `padx=10`, `pady=10`

If this is what you want on screenshot.

Code:

```
root.geometry("850x450")
:
:   

 Emailtxt.place(x=0, y=0)
    Emailentry.place(x=270, y=0)
    worldlisttext.place(x=0, y=50)
    worldlistentry.place(x=370, y=50)
    start.place(x=0, y=100)
```

Screenshot:

[image]